# Dynamics CRM 2015 - Retrieve all Contact that are in any way connected to Opportunity

Tags: fetchxml

I need to present all contact that have connection to opportunity in dialog. So when some opportunity has Sales Team, Stakeholders, Owners, etc. Something like Active Connection Associate View. I need a FetchXml or other ways to find all the Contact that are in any way connected to current opened Opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchXML query will look quite like this :

```
<fetch mapping='logical' version='1.0'>
  <entity name='myentity'>
<filter>
  <condition attribute='myentityid' operator='eq' value='myvalue' />
</filter>
<link-entity name='secondentity' from='stsr_materialid' to='stsr_material_casinglookup' alias='c' link-type='outer'>
  <attribute name='stsr_name' />
  <attribute name='stsr_code_aisi' />
  <attribute name='stsr_code_astm' />
  <attribute name='stsr_code_din' />
  <attribute name='stsr_code_e' />
  <attribute name='stsr_code_en' />
</link-entity>
```

If you need more help, please provide more context.